# Using the libcurl library vs calling curl using system()

Tags: c++, curl

I want my program to download some audio file from a link I give it and save it.

I know this can be easily done in the command line using `curl` (for instance: `curl -A "Mozilla" "www.example.com" > hello.mp3`

I saw examples where `system()` was used to run `curl` (i.e it looked something like `system(curl -A "Mozilla" "www.example.com" > hello.mp3)` . Even though this is an easy solution it seems bad to me.

Would it be better practice to write an equivalent code using the matching library (libcurl in this case)?

What do you guys think?

P.S - This is a general question in a sense. What I mean by that is that there are many command line programs which can be run by system() to get a fast and easy result. The question is if it's okay to use this method to achieve it.

Answer (score 3):

**Yes, it would be better to use `libcurl` directly. *That's what it exists for.***

That way, you avoid:

- the cost of a system call
- the cost of spawning a new process
- potential security-related bugs in your system call

Invoking `curl` from the shell will basically just spawn a new shell and new process for no reason, then go ahead and use `libcurl` inside that process anyway. Cut out the middle man.